# Какое слово можно образовать от слова "шоссе"?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Какое слово можно образовать от слова "шоссе"? Очень надо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно образовать слово **шоссейный**.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шоссейный_велосипед](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4)

Ещё есть такие слова:
**пришоссейный**
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/268454/Шоссировать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/268454/%D0%A8%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
**шоссейка**
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/281960/шоссейка](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/281960/%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0)
**шоссейно-кольцевой**
*Чемпионат мира по шоссейно-кольцевым мотогонкам*
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1440073
**шоссеец**
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/268452/Шоссеец](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/268452/%D0%A8%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%86)
**шоссировать**
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1093190
**шоссироваться**
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1093194
**шоссированный**
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1093186

Comment: Ещё словарями фиксируется _пришоссейный_ https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/228305/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Спасибо, добавил.

Comment: И еще: шоссейка, шоссейно-кольцевой, шоссировать.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ничего себе наплыв слов)))

Comment: Нашла дополнительно (в словаре Тихонова): шоссеец, шоссироваться, шоссированный.

Comment: Я в шоке))) У Ефремовой/Ушакова они тоже есть. Добавлено.